# Windows 10 and Ubuntu 18.04 dual boot crash

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi

I have a Lenovo E480 with Windows 10 and Ubuntu 18.04. Yesterday, the laptop could not be booted up after it went into sleep in Windows. When I tried restarting the laptop, I got the error message

```
Unexpected return from initial read:Volume Corrupt, buffersize 1000
Failed to load image \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.fi: Volume Corrupt
start_image() returned Volume Corrupt
```

I booted from a USB thumb drive version of 18.04 and tried to use boot-repair but the entire process hung for about 30 minutes before I Ctrl-C and killed the process.

I uploaded the boot-repair info to [here](https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/WTnxYygh5g/).

Could someone please kindly advise me on what I should do? Thanks!

Edit 1:

I can still boot up Windows by manually choosing the Windows bootloader from BIOS. However, I cannot boot Ubuntu 18.04.

Edit 2:
This is the readout from `boot-repair`

```
boot-repair-4ppa203                                              [20230316_0515]

============================== Boot Info Summary ===============================

 => No boot loader is installed in the MBR of /dev/nvme0n1.

nvme0n1p1: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  Windows 8/10/11/2012: FAT32
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /efi/Boot/bootx64.efi /efi/Boot/fbx64.efi 
                       /efi/ubuntu/grubx64.efi /efi/ubuntu/mmx64.efi 
                       /efi/ubuntu/shimx64.efi /efi/ubuntu/grub.cfg 
                       /efi/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi 
                       /efi/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgr.efi 
                       /efi/Microsoft/Boot/cbmr_driver.efi

nvme0n1p2: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 

nvme0n1p3: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       
    Boot sector type:  Unknown
    Boot sector info: 

nvme0n1p4: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows 8/10/11/2012: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

nvme0n1p5: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS
    Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /etc/fstab /etc/default/grub

sda: ___________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       iso9660
    Boot sector type:  Unknown
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg


================================ 1 OS detected =================================

OS#1:   Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS on nvme0n1p5

================================ Host/Hardware =================================

CPU architecture: 64-bit
Video: UHD Graphics 620 from Intel Corporation
Live-session OS is Ubuntu 64-bit (Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS, bionic, x86_64)

===================================== UEFI =====================================

BIOS/UEFI firmware: R0PET67W (1.44 ) from LENOVO
The firmware is EFI-compatible, and is set in EFI-mode for this live-session.
SecureBoot disabled (confirmed by mokutil).
BootCurrent: 001A
Timeout: 0 seconds
BootOrder: 0000,0001,0016,0017,0018,0019,001A,001B
Boot0000* ubuntu    HD(1,GPT,38042b89-9911-43e1-bf9d-17f7bab6c091,0x800,0x82000)/File(\EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi)
Boot0001* Windows Boot Manager  HD(1,GPT,38042b89-9911-43e1-bf9d-17f7bab6c091,0x800,0x82000)/File(\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootmgfw.efi)WINDOWS.........x...B.C.D.O.B.J.E.C.T.=.{.9.d.e.a.8.6.2.c.-.5.c.d.d.-.4.e.7.0.-.a.c.c.1.-.f.3.2.b.3.4.4.d.4.7.9.5.}...@A...............
Boot0010  Setup FvFile(721c8b66-426c-4e86-8e99-3457c46ab0b9)
Boot0011  Boot Menu FvFile(126a762d-5758-4fca-8531-201a7f57f850)
Boot0012  Diagnostic Splash Screen  FvFile(a7d8d9a6-6ab0-4aeb-ad9d-163e59a7a380)
Boot0013  Lenovo Diagnostics    FvFile(3f7e615b-0d45-4f80-88dc-26b234958560)
Boot0014  Startup Interrupt Menu    FvFile(f46ee6f4-4785-43a3-923d-7f786c3c8479)
Boot0015  Rescue and Recovery   FvFile(665d3f60-ad3e-4cad-8e26-db46eee9f1b5)
Boot0016* USB CD    VenMsg(bc7838d2-0f82-4d60-8316-c068ee79d25b,86701296aa5a7848b66cd49dd3ba6a55)
Boot0017* USB FDD   VenMsg(bc7838d2-0f82-4d60-8316-c068ee79d25b,6ff015a28830b543a8b8641009461e49)
Boot0018* NVMe0 VenMsg(bc7838d2-0f82-4d60-8316-c068ee79d25b,001c199932d94c4eae9aa0b6e98eb8a400)
Boot0019* ATA HDD0  VenMsg(bc7838d2-0f82-4d60-8316-c068ee79d25b,91af625956449f41a7b91f4f892ab0f600)
Boot001A* USB HDD   VenMsg(bc7838d2-0f82-4d60-8316-c068ee79d25b,33e821aaaf33bc4789bd419f88c50803)
Boot001B* PCI LAN   VenMsg(bc7838d2-0f82-4d60-8316-c068ee79d25b,78a84aaf2b2afc4ea79cf5cc8f3d3803)

728124f6ec8e22fbdbe7034812c81b95   nvme0n1p1/Boot/bootx64.efi
5dabe049a4dad758d975dc2e60a7f00e   nvme0n1p1/Boot/fbx64.efi
   nvme0n1p1/ubuntu/grubx64.efi
f243a42f3bd3164872e792dbc2610270   nvme0n1p1/ubuntu/mmx64.efi
728124f6ec8e22fbdbe7034812c81b95   nvme0n1p1/ubuntu/shimx64.efi
1218b32286c5a2baf0537f8502c8e64f   nvme0n1p1/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
d99f2df7850c1d370e73b3214660ff5d   nvme0n1p1/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgr.efi
b8796e68099026aabcebb8fcf75b21f6   nvme0n1p1/Microsoft/Boot/cbmr_driver.efi
a7d2b5a20ff5098975ba4743f80faf26   nvme0n1p1/Boot/LenovoBT.efi

============================= Drive/Partition Info =============================

Disks info: ____________________________________________________________________

nvme0n1 : is-GPT,   no-BIOSboot,    hashidESP,  not-usb,    not-mmc, has-os,    no-wind,    2048 sectors * 512 bytes

Partitions info (1/3): _________________________________________________________

nvme0n1p1   : no-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   not-far
nvme0n1p4   : no-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   farbios
nvme0n1p5   : is-os,    64, apt-get,    signed grub-pc grub-efi ,   grub2,  grub-install,   grubenv-ok, update-grub,    farbios
nvme0n1p3   : no-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   farbios

Partitions info (2/3): _________________________________________________________

nvme0n1p1   : hidenESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, recovery-or-hidden, no-bmgr,    notwinboot
nvme0n1p4   : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, recovery-or-hidden, no-bmgr,    notwinboot
nvme0n1p5   : isnotESP, fstab-has-goodEFI,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot
nvme0n1p3   : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot

Partitions info (3/3): _________________________________________________________

nvme0n1p1   : not--sepboot, no-kernel,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, nvme0n1
nvme0n1p4   : not--sepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, nvme0n1
nvme0n1p5   : not--sepboot, with-boot,  fstab-without-boot, not-sep-usr,    with--usr,  fstab-without-usr,  std-grub.d, nvme0n1
nvme0n1p3   : maybesepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, nvme0n1

fdisk -l (filtered): ___________________________________________________________

Disk nvme0n1: 477 GiB, 512110190592 bytes, 1000215216 sectors
Disk identifier: 61276A8B-92CE-4FF8-996E-8A2ACF47AA52
              Start        End   Sectors   Size Type
nvme0n1p1      2048     534527    532480   260M EFI System
nvme0n1p2    534528     567295     32768    16M Microsoft reserved
nvme0n1p3    567296  690966527 690399232 329.2G Microsoft basic data
nvme0n1p4 998166528 1000214527   2048000  1000M Windows recovery environment
nvme0n1p5 690966528  998166527 307200000 146.5G Linux filesystem
Partition table entries are not in disk order.
Disk sda: 14.3 GiB, 15376318464 bytes, 30031872 sectors
Disk identifier: 0x4c050c47
      Boot   Start     End Sectors  Size Id Type
sda1  *          0 4910399 4910400  2.3G  0 Empty
sda2       4840192 4844991    4800  2.4M ef EFI (FAT-12/16/32)

parted -lm (filtered): _________________________________________________________

sda:15.4GB:scsi:512:512:unknown:SanDisk Cruzer Spark:;
nvme0n1:512GB:nvme:512:512:gpt:WDC PC SN720 SDAQNTW-512G-1001:;
1:1049kB:274MB:273MB:fat32:EFI system partition:boot, hidden, esp;
2:274MB:290MB:16.8MB::Microsoft reserved partition:msftres;
3:290MB:354GB:353GB::Basic data partition:msftdata;
5:354GB:511GB:157GB:ext4::;
4:511GB:512GB:1049MB:ntfs::hidden, diag;

blkid (filtered): ______________________________________________________________

NAME        FSTYPE   UUID                                 PARTUUID                             LABEL                    PARTLABEL
sda         iso9660  2021-09-15-20-41-59-00                                                    Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS amd64 
├─sda1      iso9660  2021-09-15-20-41-59-00               4c050c47-01                          Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS amd64 
└─sda2      vfat     7E74-30B0                            4c050c47-02                          Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS amd64 
nvme0n1                                                                                                                 
├─nvme0n1p1 vfat     FE53-31E8                            38042b89-9911-43e1-bf9d-17f7bab6c091 SYSTEM                   EFI system partition
├─nvme0n1p2                                               7b11e182-ca92-4b9c-b485-56530423203d                          Microsoft reserved partition
├─nvme0n1p3                                               bb2ddc07-365f-4d29-98ab-dd1ef446d379                          Basic data partition
├─nvme0n1p4 ntfs     B4685674685634F8                     96abe525-f2f8-4323-9830-9361c16a6ecb WinRE_DRV                Basic data partition
└─nvme0n1p5 ext4     bfe66b32-560e-4d81-b14b-94d0d13423d7 27928954-f5db-4664-a06c-2962af427f36                          

Mount points (filtered): _______________________________________________________

                        Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/nvme0n1p1           218M  15% /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p1
/dev/nvme0n1p4         376.5M  62% /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p4
/dev/nvme0n1p5          74.6G  43% /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p5
/dev/sda                    0 100% /cdrom

Mount options (filtered): ______________________________________________________


=================== nvme0n1p1/efi/ubuntu/grub.cfg (filtered) ===================

search.fs_uuid bfe66b32-560e-4d81-b14b-94d0d13423d7 root 
set prefix=($root)'/boot/grub'
configfile $prefix/grub.cfg

=================== nvme0n1p5/boot/grub/grub.cfg (filtered) ====================

Ubuntu   bfe66b32-560e-4d81-b14b-94d0d13423d7
Ubuntu, with Linux 5.4.0-144-generic   bfe66b32-560e-4d81-b14b-94d0d13423d7
Ubuntu, with Linux 5.4.0-137-generic   bfe66b32-560e-4d81-b14b-94d0d13423d7
Windows Boot Manager (on nvme0n1p1)   osprober-efi-FE53-31E8
### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
System setup   uefi-firmware
### END /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###

======================== nvme0n1p5/etc/fstab (filtered) ========================

# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/nvme0n1p5 during installation
UUID=bfe66b32-560e-4d81-b14b-94d0d13423d7 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/nvme0n1p1 during installation
UUID=FE53-31E8  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0

==================== nvme0n1p5/etc/default/grub (filtered) =====================

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

================= nvme0n1p5: Location of files loaded by Grub ==================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)
 379.957035065 = 407.975759872  boot/grub/grub.cfg                             3
 411.988731384 = 442.369531904  boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-137-generic                 2
 467.059055328 = 501.500841984  boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-144-generic                 1
 467.059055328 = 501.500841984  vmlinuz                                        1
 411.988731384 = 442.369531904  vmlinuz.old                                    2
 466.505847931 = 500.906840064  boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-137-generic              5
 386.448936462 = 414.946385920  boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-137-generic.old-dkms     5
 346.442714691 = 371.990032384  boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-144-generic              3
 346.442714691 = 371.990032384  initrd.img                                     3
 466.505847931 = 500.906840064  initrd.img.old                                 5

=================== nvme0n1p5: ls -l /etc/grub.d/ (filtered) ===================

-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 12808 Aug 24  2020 10_linux
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 11298 Feb  7  2019 20_linux_xen
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 12059 Feb  7  2019 30_os-prober
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  1418 Feb  7  2019 30_uefi-firmware
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   214 Feb  7  2019 40_custom
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   216 Feb  7  2019 41_custom

====================== sda/boot/grub/grub.cfg (filtered) =======================

Try Ubuntu without installing
Install Ubuntu
OEM install (for manufacturers)
Check disc for defects

==================== sda: Location of files loaded by Grub =====================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)
            ?? = ??             boot/grub/grub.cfg                             1



Suggested repair: ______________________________________________________________

The default repair of the Boot-Repair utility would reinstall the grub-efi of
nvme0n1p5,
using the following options:  nvme0n1p1/boot/efi
Additional repair would be performed: unhide-bootmenu-10s use-standard-efi-file

Final advice in case of suggested repair: ______________________________________

Please do not forget to make your UEFI firmware boot on the Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS entry (nvme0n1p1/efi/****/grub****.efi (**** will be updated in the final message) file) !
```

Comment: I would not have run boot repair; given your description it sounds like it was not cleanly shutdown, thus a *file-system check* of partitions would have been my choice (ie. boot live media & perform `fsck` of partition(s), if any error(s) were found & fixed, I'd expect normal operation on next boot).   FYI:  You are aware Ubuntu 18.04 LTS reaches the end of it's five years of *standard* support next month; ie. 2018-April + 5 years, so consider your *release-upgrade* path rather soon.

Comment: Thank you. How do you use ```fsck``` to clean the partition(s)? I see 5 partitions: (1) ```EFI System```, (2) ```Microsoft reserved```, (3) ```Microsoft basic data```, (4) ```Windows recovery environmen```, (5) ```Linux filesystem```. I also see the line ```Partition table entries are not in disk order```.

Comment: The ESP (*EFI System partition*) is only ever changed during system upgrades; so unless you were performing system upgrades that should be okay (*but a check won't hurt as I'd not expect it to find any errors*), as only one remaining partition is likely Ubuntu related, that's what I'd `fsck`. Boot *live* media & use a command, `gnome-disk-utility`, `gparted` or whatever tool you're familiar with to check file-system for errors (ie. logical errors; it won't check for bad sectors etc, just logical errors that can cause failure to boot, failure to read data etc...)

Comment: "You need to be logged in to view this paste." ... I won't login...

Comment: @paladin, I added the paste to the original question.